# Change boost_zlib DLL name when compiling iostreams library in Boost?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, dll, boost-iostreams

I'm compiling the **iostreams** library in Boost in Windows. It appears that it creates a **boost_zlib*.dll** file automatically. I want to create two versions of the iostreams **.lib** and **.dll** files with separate names for both 32 and 64 bits to put into the same folder. I can easily rename the "iostreams" files. I also need to place the "boost_zlib" files in the same folder. However, since "boost_zlib" file are created automatically, I can't just rename them.

Is there a way to specify the "boost_zlib" output file name so that I can append a "32" or "64" to the file name in order for me to place both files in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could simply rename the files and use those.

I assume you are indeed on windows, so you should also rename the corresponding .lib files then.

Auto-linking will probably not work anymore with any change in the naming (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#identify-your-toolset, last line).

It looks like you could actually copy the toolset definition for your compiler into a 64/32 bit copy and append the architecture identification to the toolset name.

The tagged naming scheme will insert the toolset name into the library file names (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming).